# Semi-direct file access vs index.php controller

Tags: php, html, nginx, seo, url-rewriting

Quick question I've had here which is a bit of a dilemma.
I have searched already but cant find a concise answer.

I currently have on my website which is php based, a global index.php file which serves all requests so there's included in that file, a header, center part, a footer. This is globally setup for every page so that all that changes is the site center - see code below:

```
require_once("assets/template/$theme_name/header.php"); //Global Header
require_once('process.php'); //Site Center
require_once('assets/template/default/footer.php'); //Global Foote
```

This has worked fine so far, and I'm currently using a query string to do the rest (nginx converting website.com/index.php?pg=pagename to website.com/pagename

What I'm wondering is whether it would be safe and beneficial to just include the header and footer on each page, and have every user access the page via the actual page file which is located in a pages folder. Or is my current method good? Any effect on SEO?
I already have nginx rewrite code put together (just not implemented) so that website.com/pagename will be accessing website.com/pages/pagename.php

Please let me know your opinion!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about doing is called refactoring. You're changing the implementation without having any noticeable effect on your users. The refactoring, in and of itself, won't affect SEO.

Now to what, in my opinion, is the more interesting question: why are you considering doing this change? From my vantage point, making this change will increase the amout of duplicated code (aka reduce the amount of code re-use). Such a change would violate some core precepts of good software engineering.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm just doing this change so that newrelic can tell me which page is most inefficient - seeing a breakdown only for index.php is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> "I already have nginx rewrite code set so that website.com/pagename
>   will be accessing website.com/pages/pagename.php"

does that mean you are redirecting /pages/pagename.php to /pagename, or that you are simply showing the appropriate content regardless of URL?

If you are redirecting, make sure your rewrites/redirects are 301s and you should be OK. Note that a little bit of search authority is lost on 301 redirects, so ideally you wouldn't have to redirect URLs at all. That said, it won't make a huge difference.

If you are not redirecting and just ensuring that both URLs are showing the same content, make sure you use a canonical tag on URLs that show identical content.

Put this on any duplicate content pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com/pagename" />
```

Unless of course you use www in your url, then use:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.website.com/pagename" />
```